# Tensorflow training stops without any errors or warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory

I am making an AI in python that recognizes handwritten letters. I have a script that trains on custom *`.npy`* files instead of the mnist dataset. But it whenever I run it, it stops without any errors at all, almost immediately. If I try running it in Jupyter notebook, it shuts down the kernel and doesn't give any output.
I'm suspecting it's an *OOM* error, I have tried to make the batch size smaller, but it still gave the same error.

This is where I got the code from: https://github.com/dbusteed/alphabet_quiz/blob/master/app.py

(full video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpWIf-iH7DA&t=834s&ab_channel=DavisBusteed)

The full error message from atom:

```
2022-08-31 14:17:29.127118: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-08-31 14:17:30.185406: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3497 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Epoch 1/10
2022-08-31 14:17:33.432554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8400
[Finished in 19.892s]
```

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from bidict import bidict
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


ENCODER = bidict({
    'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6,
    'G': 7, 'H': 8, 'I': 9, 'J': 10, 'K': 11, 'L': 12,
    'M': 13, 'N': 14, 'O': 15, 'P': 16, 'Q': 17, 'R': 18,
    'S': 19, 'T': 20, 'U': 21, 'V': 22, 'W': 23, 'X': 24,
    'Y': 25, 'Z': 26
})

labels = np.load('data/labels.npy')
labels = np.array([ENCODER[x] for x in labels])
print(labels.shape)

imgs = np.load('data/images.npy')
imgs = imgs.astype("float32") / 255
print(imgs.shape)

imgs = np.expand_dims(imgs, -1)
print(imgs.shape)


labels, imgs = shuffle(labels, imgs)
split = .75

labels_train = labels[:int(len(labels) * split)]
labels_test = labels[int(len(labels) * split):]

imgs_train = imgs[:int(len(imgs) * split)]
imgs_test = imgs[int(len(imgs) * split):]

batch_size = 32
epochs = 10

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=(50, 50, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(len(ENCODER)+1, activation='softmax')
])

early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuracy", patience=2)
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(imgs_train,
            labels_train,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            validation_data=(imgs_test, labels_test),
            callbacks=[early_stopping])

model.save("alphabet_detection.h5")
```

Comment: Me also having same error with tf 2.9.2 and rtx 3090. After some error without any error just stops training...

Comment: You can check how much GPU memory you are using with the `nvidia-smi` command. I use this command to see whether or not an application continues to take more and more GPU memory. Also, use a try-catch block. It will give you more information about any errors that are reported. (GPU OOM is reported as an exception at runtime.) If you're not getting an error at runtime, it's not an OOM error.